# "no A and B" or "no A and no B" or "no A or B" or "no A or no B"?

Tags: grammar

If I mean "it does not contain A or B", which one of the following is correct?

1. It contains no A and B.
2. It contains no A and no B.
3. It contains no A or B.
4. It contains no A or no B.

I think 2 is correct, but I am not sure about others.

Comment: Are you sure this in a question about English?  It seems more like a question about logic.

Comment: Although I can't answer this thoroughly, I can definitely say that 4) is wrong.

Comment: There is a difficulty here. Standard English usage of "no" with "and" and "or" does *not* match the mathematical or Computer Science usage. If you're asking about common English usage, "it does not contain A or B" is correct; none of the other options would be standard informal usage.

Answer (score 1):

‘**It contains neither A nor B’** is how you can express this correctly in English.

‘Either / or’ and ‘neither / nor’ are matching pairs.

https://thewritepractice.com/how-to-use-either-neither-or-and-nor-correctly/

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem of using "**It does not contain A or B**"?

You can add "**any**" for emphasis.

If you mean "both A and B" altogether simply say "It doesn't contain both A and B".